# CLLocationManager run loop

Tags: iphone, uialertview, cllocationmanager

I''m getting an infinite loop with the below code. When a user hits the "getDirections" method button, the alert fires correctly. When the choose "Get Drections" from alert buttons, google maps works perfectly. When they re-open the app, it opens back to this view and the app immediately goes back to google maps, rerunning the method again. THe only way I can stop this is to have the "Application does not run in background" turned to YES, which I don't want to do.

Can Someone tell my why this is happening?

```
-(IBAction)getDirections
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Directions" message:@"Do you want driving directions?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No Thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"Get Directions", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

-(void)showDirections
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [newLocation coordinate];
    NSArray *array = [dataHold objectForKey:@"Subtree"];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:4]];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:5]];
    double clubLatitude = [latitude doubleValue];
    double clubLongitude = [longitude doubleValue];
    urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude, clubLatitude, clubLongitude];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
        buttonString = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
        if([buttonString isEqualToString:@"Get Directions"] )
        {
            [self showDirections];
            buttonString = nil;
        }
        else if( [buttonString isEqualToString:@"No Thanks"] )
        {
            nil;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the following piece of code. You should add it to the 
    (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation method

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

Answer (score 2):

The `didUpdateToLocation` delegate method is called constantly once you ccll `CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocatoin`.

Thus your code inside that `didUpdateToLocation` is called every time the location is updated - even when you launch the app back from the background. 
And the method is called a lot depending on the `distanceFilter` propery of your locationManager. You can confirm this by adding a `NSLog` statement to your delegate method and see how many times it is being called.

The Docs on that method:

> Discussion Implementation of this method is optional. You should
>   implement this method, however.
>
> By the time this message is delivered to your delegate, the new
>   location data is also available directly from the CLLocationManager
>   object. The newLocation parameter may contain the data that was cached
>   from a previous usage of the location service. You can use the
>   timestamp property of the location object to determine how recent the
>   location data is.

Follow that guide and save a timeStamp (or any other kind of identifier) inside the didUpdateToLocation method.

Once you have set the timeStamp, you can display the google maps using those values. Sidenote:  Your CLLocationManager has a property `location` that gets updates every time the `didUpdateToLocation` is called - thus you can rely on that property to get the current location elsewhere in your code.

HTH

Comment: Shaharyar,  since I only needed one didUpdateToLocation, I called stopUpdatingLocation at the end of the didUpdateToLocation method. Worked great. Thanks so much!